# Multiple/Stacking PageAdapter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Question is... can I stack multiple PageAdapter(s) in my ASP.NET website?
I have a project which has already its own PageAdapter classes applied but I need to add one to move viewstate so that is persisted on server (disk, db, cache, whatever).
My doubt is... If I create a page adapter for "default" browser (so for every browser) and that project already has its adapters for different browsers for some stuff, will my adapter stack flawlessly with those or there can be only one page adapter at time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapters are stored in [`HttpCapabilitiesBase.Adapters`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Configuration/HttpCapabilitiesBase.cs#b492c85ec4fb7b7c#references) property as `Hashtable`. If you will observe this collection in debug you will see that the key for this `Hashtable` is a fully qualified name of the page/control type.

So it is not possible to stack control adapters, there is always one adapter per control at a time. And the default browser definition always wins (of course except the cases when you are filling page adapters collection manually).

Comment: Thank you... this will be a problem I guess for me. I'm afraid that if I add my page adapter I will break the logic with the existing ones. What do you mean with "of course except the cases when you are filling page adapters collection manually"?

Comment: @Manight adapters could be registered programmatically, usually in page constructor or since the `Request` object is available.

And if your task is only to move view state from client to server you can use technique described in ASP.NET Page State Persister article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479403.aspx).

Comment: Didn't know about adding the base page type in web.config... nice solution, I wonder how this would interact with other base pages class already inherited from pages.

Comment: Base page type will work only if `aspx` does not contain `Inherits`, `CodeBehind` or `CodeFile` page attributes.

Comment: I supposed that... I think I'll have to resort to page adapter and eventually tamper the pre-existing .browser files. Thanks for your help